# Define custom loss with class weight argument in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, loss-function

I wanted to use focal loss for my imbalanced tabular data. I used Tensorflow API  [Focal Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryFocalCrossentropy), but it is not working. My goal is to use focal loss with class weight as custom loss function. There are other ways to do it, but I wanted to use tensorflow API.

```
np.random.seed(16)
python_random.seed(17)
tf.random.set_seed(18)
model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (50, 5),return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryFocalCrossentropy(
    apply_class_balancing=True, gamma=2, from_logits=True)
              , metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]
              , optimizer=adam)

model.summary()
```

I got the following error, not sure why! I appreciate your suggestions.

```
TypeError: BinaryFocalCrossentropy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'apply_class_balancing'
```

Comment: What tf version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.9.1 version.

Comment: You should use the v2.9 documentation. `BinaryFocalCrossentropy` does not have an `apply_class_balancing` keyword in v2.9

Comment: Hi @ForestGump, kindly upgrade your Tensorflow to 2.10 as the `apply_class_balancing` argument is available in `TF v2.10`. Thank you!